# Should I security sanitise web contact page text that's emailed to me?

Tags: html, security, xss

I have a contact-us page on a website. It asks for your name, your thoughts and has a check box to ask if you'd like to make your thoughts public.   The contents of this page are then emailed to a gmail account.  The actual publishing (if okayed) is done manually by a person /monkey. There are no attachments of any sort. There's probably tens of pages like this across the Interweb.

By sanitising, I mean for security /hacking prevention.  So removal of strange html characters like < and >, escape characters and semicolons etc.  Bogus form input from bots that might attempt cross site scripting stuff when viewed with a browser and things like that.  I don't mean profanity, bad spelling or dodgy opinions.

I don't think that there is actually any point sanitising the text as it goes   servlet -> smtp servers -> gmail -> Chrome browser.  I expect that Google does a far better job at sanitising dodgey email text than I ever could. Is there anything to the contrary?

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte Which bit?

Comment: pretty much all of it. What you are trying to actually achieve is not clearly defined. Not enough context to give an answer here, what is your actual question?

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to read these e-mails using standard e-mail clients, then it's not going to pose danger, other than usual risks of phishing, tracking, and in worst case injection of dangerous attachment that you shouldn't be opening anyway. E-mail clients already try to isolate and santize any incoming content. However, if you were do display this content elsewhere, e.g. in a CRM or an admin panel of the site, then XSS risk is much higher.

- If you're sending HTML e-mail, then all usual HTML escaping rules apply (at minimum change `<` to `&lt;`, `&` to `&amp;`).
- If you're sending plain text email, then any text in there is just text, so you shouldn't need to do anything. However, just in case don't let attacker-supplied text at the very beginning of the e-mail (insert some intro like "user has sent this:"), so they can't insert [uuencode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding) header.
- Be extra careful about putting user-submitted values in headers such as `Subject`/`From`/`Reply-To`. If your e-mail sending library doesn't handle escaping of these fields, you will have to handle it (e.g. apply quoted-printable). It's also essential to prevent newlines from being inserted in these fields, as this could be abused for header injection and spam (e.g. even if your form has 1-line `<input>` for name, an attacker can submit a whole formatted e-mail with headers and body in there and make you send whatever they want to whoever they want).